# Why does my BlueTooth keyboard occasionally switch to typing symbols?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth, keybindings

I'm using a Microsoft Surface Ergonomic keyboard with BlueTooth connection.

[image]

Technically it is only supported on Windows 10, but it works fine on my M1 MacBook Pro running Big Sur 11.1

The issue is that occasionally it switches into a strange mode whereby the keys enter unknown characters/symbols:

`†˙´ œ¨ˆç˚ ∫®ø∑˜ ƒø≈ ∆¨µπß ø√´® †˙´ ¬åΩ¥ ∂ø©`

That should be:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

The characters may be 'symbols' - https://lingojam.com/SymbolLanguageTranslator is able to translate them back into English.

This happens sporadically and unpredictably, usually after the laptop has gone into screen-saver mode or otherwise been unused for a while. It hasn't happened (yet) while I've been actively using the laptop or keyboard.

To restore the keyboard I need to disconnect its BlueTooth connection, then reconnect. This usually fixes the issue, although I sometimes need to repeat the process.

Here are the Keyboard settings:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions to avoid this problem?

Comment: Your Option key is stuck down - presumably as you have it remapped, actually your Windows key.

Comment: The "symbols" are simply what every Mac produces with the option key held down with the US input source, e.g. "dog" becomes ∂ø©.

Comment: huh, I never knew that. Why would anyone want to type those symbols?! It looks like a possible software fault on the keyboard since it's new and the key is definitely not physically sticking. I'll see whether I can toggle the mode off next time the fault occurs. Thanks for the info

Comment: If you don’t need the keys just create a new keyboard layout using ukulele with out the keys. Keyboard shortcuts I believe(I have not tested this) should still work.

Comment: The error just occurred again and unfortunately hitting the Option/Windows key makes no difference. So it looks like a software fault with the keyboard - this may be why it's not officially supported on a Mac ;)

Comment: I don't want to jinx things, but the keyboard has been working perfectly for the past year or so. Presumably Apple updated something somewhere, since I haven't made any changes